# jetty WebSocket custom events

Tags: java, servlets, websocket, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I am new to WebSockets with jetty, before I have used node.js together with socket.io to create a WebSocket Server. But due to different requirements I will have to use a java WebSocketServlet/WebSocket and was doing well so far using maven, jetty and the jetty-websocket plugin. My problem is, that I don´t found anything what was comparable to socket.io's socket.on(event, fn) implementation for the java solution. I would like to have the same possibility to react on different events fired from the client like "new", "addthis", "jointhat", ... send with some data as json or as POST param in the body. Is there any possibility or WebSocket Implementation which could do the same as socket.io?
Doing this "channel" stuff where I can implement the eventhandling on server side?

Answer (score 2):

There is no custom event in WebSocket spec, and socket.io just follows their own protocol supporting custom event - https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-spec

As far as I know, there is no Java implementation supporting custom event listening.

However, with Atmosphere, you can use socket.io client with Java web server, but I have not tested. https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Getting-Started-with-Socket.IO

You might want to use other library in the client side like the jQuery Socket, if you want to control Jetty's WebSocketServlet directly. - https://github.com/flowersinthesand/jquery-socket/tree/master/samples/jetty-ws

Answer (score 1):

Jetty's websocket implementation is only concerned with handling the basics of websocket.

- Binary Messages (with fragmenting)
- Text Messages (with fragmenting)
- Ping / Pong
- Close

There's been some brief discussion on supporting various new websocket subprotocols (odd name), such as [WAMP](http://wamp.ws/spec) (websocket application messaging protocol).  But those would just be built on top of the basic websocket layer.

Another choice is to use something with a full channel api like [CometD](http://cometd.org/) and just configure it to use websocket and not fallback into older communication formats.